# nodejs referenceerror on nested function calls using async.series and async.until

Tags: node.js, async.js

I'm new to nodejs and trying to learn the basics by rebuilding an existing i2c  sensor system.
Got it all running using a named functions and async.series inside a single file. To keep make reusable i now want to create a class which i then can import. unfortunatly i get some errors i don't understand.

**class.js**

```
const async = require('async');
const i2c = require('i2c-bus');
class Sensor {
  constructor (channel) {
    this.channel = channel;
    var self = this;
  }
  openBus (callback) {
    bus = i2c.open(self.channel, (err) => {callback()}); // shorted for stackoverflow
  }
  closeBus (callback) {
    bus.close( (err) => {callback()}); //also shorted for better readability
  }
  connection (callback) {
    /* first variation */
    async.series([openBus, closeBus], callback);
  connection2 (callback) {
    /* second variation */
    async.series([this.openBus, this.closeBus], callback);
  }
}
module.exports = K30;
```

when i import the class, i can without any problem create a new sensor 'object' and call the functions directly using:

```
> var Sensor = require('./class.js');
> var mySensor = new Sensor(1);
> mySensor.openBus(foo);
> mySensor.closeBus(bar);
```

but if i go an try call the wrapper-functions, i get the following errors:

```
> mySensor.connection(foo);
ReferenceError: openBus is not defined (at 'connection')
> mySensor.connection2(foo);
ReferenceError: self is not defined (at 'openBus')
```

i believe those errors occure due to my lack of understanding the correct usage of this and self. sadly i can't find any good ead on that topic. any help is highly appreciated.

***UPDATE***

the solution provided in the first two anwsers was in fact my first approch before starting to use "self" (after some googling [this-that-trick]).
anyways, here is the output/error i get using "this.channel" instead:

```
> mySensor.connection2(foo);
TypeError: Cannot read property 'channel' of undefined (at openBus)
```

Comment: i temporarily fixed the problem by declaring 'channel' as a global variable outside the class.

Answer (score 0):

This is not saved anywhere `var self = this;` and therefore is lost when the function (constructor is function) ends.

Just remove the above line in constructor and use everywhere the `this` instead of `self`.

Its true that `this` keyword is little tricky in javascript, but if you follow reasonable approach, you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You indeed have issue with `this` and `self`

Every member inside the class has to be referred by `this`. If you declare a variable named `var EBZ-Krisemendt = "SO user";`, to access it, you need to use it with this, eg: `console.log(this.EBZ-Krisemendt);`

What you need here is

```
openBus (callback) {
    bus = i2c.open(this.channel, (err) => {callback()});
  }
```

and then `mysensor.connection2(foo)` will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

while i still don't fully understand the reason behind this i fixed my code by getting rid of that "ES6" class definition.

**class.js**

```
const i2c   = require('i2c-bus');
const async = require('async');
function Sensor(channel) {
  let that = this; // make 'this' available in sub-function scope
  this.channel = channel;

  function openBus(cb) {
    // open the bus-connection
    bus = i2c.open(that.channel);
  }
  function closeBus(cb) {
    // close the bus-connection
  }
  function connection(cb) {
    async.series([openBus, closeBus], cb);
  }
  function getReading(cb) {
    async.until(
      function() {
        // loop condition e.g. max tries to get reading
      },
      function(cb) {
        connection(cb); // calling nested synchronous connection-routine
      },
      function (err) {
        // result handling
      }
    ); // end async.until
  } // end getReading

  return {
    getReading: getReading
  } // make only 'getReading' available
}
module.exports = {
  Sensor: Sensor
} // make 'Sensor' available
```

in the 'member'-functions i can now use the 'class'-variables of 'Sensor' by accessing them with 'that' (e.g.: 'that.channel')

***Detail:***

```
function openBus(cb){
  bus = i2c.open(that.channel);
}
```

if i'd use *this* instead of *that* it would only work while calling *openBus* directly. in my example it's neccessary to call *openBus* and *closeBus* in a synchronous manner (for obvious reasons). since *async.series* is additionally nested inside *async.until* (sensor might need several tries to response) the scope of *this* changes. by using *that* instead i'm able to ignore the scope.

***Comment:***
since the solution is kinda generally pointing to using nested async-calls inside custom modules i'll slightly alter the titel of the initial question. i'm still hoping for better solutions and/or explanations, so i won't mark my own anwser as accepted yet.